# sizeWithFont with MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

What's the equivalent of sizeWithFont in MonoTouch. If there's no such method, is it possible to invoke it some other way?

All I want to do is resize the label based on the text...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The next update (MonoTouch 1.1) will have the methods available as UIView.StringSize (string str, UIFont font)

Comment: Thanks Miguel, for the update. I must add you guys did a great job with MonoTouch...

Comment: I have MonoTouch 5.0 and it is unavailable.  Is there a different approach in MT 5?

Comment: It is available in MonoTouch 5.0

Comment: In the current version this is actually the non-static `NSString.StringSize()`

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question... Use selectors to pimboke the objective-c methods:

http://monotouch.net/index.php?title=Documentation/Objective-C_Selectors

Comment: Changing the accepted answer as this should still work, miguel.de.icaza's answer is a better fit

Answer (score 0):

The NSString StringSize method would work for a single line label.